# a[ ][3] How many rows have been created in this array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

For example:

```
int a[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)

    printf("%d",a[j][i]);
```

My question is: I want know how I can be able to find out how many rows (not the size of the array) have been created in this array within the `for loops`?

Comment: `printf("%d", sizeof(a));` ?!

Comment: `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)`

Comment: But it shows the size of array ... but i wanted to know the number of row created

Comment: @Rizier123 `sizeof(a)` is **not** the count of elements unless `sizeof(int)` is `1` (which is highly *unlikely*). Apart form the format specifier, the second part is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)` to get the row of array.

like this:

```
int main(){

int a[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

printf("%d",sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));//3
}
```

here if you will do `sizeof(a)` it will give `36` which tells the size not no. of rows.

Comment: "to get the size of array." - `sizeof(a)` gives you the size of the array. I think you're referring to the number of arrays in the array of arrays (which is what `a` really is). Iow, your answer is correct; the description is otherwise.

Comment: I think if you will do sizeof(a) it will give 36.

Comment: Likely, which is indeed the size of the array in bytes.